# Reading global JavaScript variable from Elm

Tags: javascript, elm

I'm currently building a small component of a web app in Elm. The elm component is compiled to a JavaScript file, loaded and then mounted on a DOM node. It should then read a config object from `window.config`. (This is not something I can change.)

How can I e.g. read a string from `window.config.title` to use in my Elm component? I've looked at ports, but it seems to require me to modify the generated JavaScript or wrap something around it. Is that the only option? If so, how would I simply read the value of a variable?

Comment: Does the config change over the lifetime of the app? If not, I'd recommend passing in the values when you initialize your elm component with [Html.programWithFlags](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/html/1.0.0/Html-App#programWithFlags)

Comment: It doesn't. That's probably what I want. I'll play around with that tomorrow. Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Edit:** Updated to Elm 0.19

If your configuration does not change over the lifetime of your app, you will probably be best served by using [Browser.element](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm/browser/latest/Browser#element) or [Platform.worker](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm/core/latest/Platform#worker).

This allows for your `main` function to accept a single value from Javascript during initialization. That single value can be a simple javascript object or it can even contain nested properties. The important thing is defining its shape inside Elm.

Let's say your javascript configuration looks like this:

```html
<script>
  window.options = {
    foo: 123,
    nested: { bar: "abc" }
  };
</script>
```

In order to be able to pass that into your Elm file, you can define a matching shape like this:

```elm
type alias Flags =
  { foo : Int
  , nested : { bar : String }
  }
```

Now you can use `Browser.element` or `Platform.worker` in your Elm file like this, defining an `init` function that takes `Flags` as an argument:

```elm
import Html exposing (..)
import Browser
import String

main =
  Browser.element
    { init = init
    , view = view
    , update = update
    , subscriptions = subscriptions
    }

init : Flags -> (Model, Cmd Msg)
init flags =
  ( { introText = String.concat
    [ "foo is "
    , String.fromInt flags.foo
    , " and nested.bar is "
    , flags.nested.bar
    ]
    },
    Cmd.none
  )
```

The last piece of the puzzle is to pass your Javascript configuration option to Elm during initialization. Your html and javascript should look something like this (the relevant portion is in passing `window.options` as the `flags` parameter of `init()`):

```html
<body>
  <div id="myContainer"></div>
  <script src="Main.js"></script>
  <script>
    var app = Elm.Main.init( {
      node: document.getElementById("myContainer"),
      flags: window.options
    } );
  </script>
</body>
```

[Here is a working example on ellie-app.](https://ellie-app.com/4Q6jvC84Y8Ga1)

Comment: This is thorough and very readable example of how to do this in Elm v0.17 (there used to be different ways of achieving the same goal, but those Static ways were removed in v0.17). This answer should be included in the official Elm documentation. Note, however, that Elm is a young language and breaking changes often occur between versions.